# Angular 5 HTML Comp. Missing TS Comp.'s Function?

Tags: angular, typescript, jhipster

A function I've written in the TypeScript portion of my Angular component seems to be invisible to the HTML which should be able to call it, but other functions in the same file can be called.

The **loadPage(page + 1)** function is successfully called, but the timedLoadResults() function isn't. Ialso tried the ng-keyup directive, but that didn't produce the function call results (verified from the browser's network traffic, makes an API call to server on execution).

Browser error is: **'timedLoadResults' is undefined**

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="searchTextId" [(ngModel)]="searchText" name="searchText" placeholder="Search" onkeyup="timedLoadResults()" >
<div id="workflowsTable" class="table-responsive" *ngIf="onlineAcceptanceWorkflows">
    <table class="table table-striped">
//table headers...
        <tbody infinite-scroll (scrolled)="loadPage(page + 1)" [infiniteScrollDisabled]="page >= links['last']" [infiniteScrollDistance]="0">
            <tr *ngFor="let onlineAcceptanceWorkflow of (onlineAcceptanceWorkflows | customSearch: searchText) ;trackBy: trackId">

//...
```

TS:

```
loadPage(page) {
    this.page = (this.searchText != '')
                ? this.page
                : page;
    this.loadAll();
}

timedLoadResults() {
    if(this.searchText == ''){
        return;
    } else {
        if(this.timeOut != null) clearTimeout(this.timeOut);
        this.timeOut = setTimeout(() => this.loadPage(0), 150);
    }
}
```

Comment: `onkeyup` is an event. So you need to specify it as `(keyup)="timedLoadResults()"`

Comment: Thanks Gunner! Worked like a charm. Post that as the solution so I can approve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason `timedLoadResults` isn't being called is due to the fact that it isn't bound to the `keyup` event. To bind to the event use `(keyup)="timedLoadResults()"` instead of `onkeyup`.

Comment: Thanks for this. Inherited a big project from a recently departed senior dev, and my background in Angular was maintaining a fairly static Angular 1.0 web app. You're a life saver.